# Copying a rowset from table to a rowset message

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am having an issue copying a rowset (that is populated from a table) to a rowset type message.

This is what I have (took out a lot of tries that failed many times)

```
Local Message &MSG;
Local Rowset &HDR_RS, &LN_RS;

&MSG = CreateMessage(Operation.TEST_SC_ASYNC_IB);
&HDR_RS = CreateRowset(Record.FUND_TBL);
&HDR_RS.Fill();
```

My goal is to add the HDR_RS rowset that is filled to the Message

This is the solution:

```
&MSG = CreateMessage(Operation.TEST_SC_ASYNC_IB);
&HDR_RS = CreateRowset(Record.FUND_TBL);
&HDR_RS.Fill();
&MSG.CopyRowset(&HDR_RS);
%IntBroker.Publish(&MSG);
```

Comment: Edited to add the solution.